# Yii update Button label

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I'm implementing a like button in yii,when i click on the button it calls a controller action which increases the number of likes by 1, i show the changed value in the Button label,how do i do it?

here is my view,what do i change ?

```
<?php $id =$data->id;
        $foo = $data->likes;
     echo CHtml::ajaxbutton($foo.' '.'Likes',
        array('post/like/'.$id),
array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'success'=>'js:function(data){ 

            ')
);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following

```
<?php $id =$data->id;
        $foo = $data->likes;
     echo CHtml::ajaxbutton($foo.' '.'Likes',
        array('post/like/'.$id),
array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'replace'=>'#buttonId')
),
array(
     'id'=>'buttonId'
);


?>
```

However, I suggest using sending parameters as data for AJAX like this:

```
<?php $id =$data->id;
        $foo = $data->likes;
     echo CHtml::ajaxbutton($foo.' '.'Likes',
        array('post/like),
array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'data'=>array("id"=>$id),
        'replace'=>'#buttonId')
),
array(
     'id'=>'buttonId'
);


?>
```

Comment: whats the Buttin id here i just say CHtml::ajaxButton right,where does the button id come from.

Comment: THe yii ajax button does not have an ID

Comment: You can add the id as part of the htmloptions of the button

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail

```
replace: string, specifies the selector whose target should be replaced by the AJAX
```